# Symfony 4 - KnpPaginator Bundle "service not found, even though it exists in app's container"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been following tutorials, and all instructions show it's done the exact same way, but it doesn't seem to work in Symfony 4. Is there something I'm overlooking or is the bundle simply incompatible?

I ran: `composer require knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle`

It was loaded automatically into `bundles.php`, thanks to Flex.

Inserted the following into `config/services.yaml`:

```
knp_paginator:
    page_range:                 5          # default page range used in pagination control
    default_options:
        page_name:              page       # page query parameter name
        sort_field_name:        sort       # sort field query parameter name
        sort_direction_name:    direction  # sort direction query parameter name
        distinct:               true       # ensure distinct results, useful when ORM queries are using GROUP BY statements
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig     # sliding pagination controls template
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig                         # sort link template
```

Tried to use the following in the controller:

```
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
```

and got the following error:

> Service "knp_paginator" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\PhotoController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services. Unless you need extra laziness, try using dependency injection instead. Otherwise, you need to declare it using "PhotoController::getSubscribedServices()".

Comment: Based on the error, it seems to me, I might've placed the knp_paginator yaml setup in the wrong place. But I can't find a place to put it without it crashing and saying it doesn't belong "there". When I place it indented from "services" it says "The configuration key "page_range" is unsupported for definition "knp_paginator"", which is.. lame..

Comment: Try to create a new file into the config/packages directory with a name like 'knppaginator.yaml' and place your configuration in your new file instead of services.yaml

Comment: Tried knp_paginator.yaml and knppaginator.yaml, no luck, same error. Funny though, I try messing with the configuration by purposefully mistyping it to knpS_paginator, it throws error saying "there is no extension able to load ...", so it knows knp_paginator is correct.

Comment: Tried it by my self. Made a file config/packages/knp_paginator.yaml and put configuration into it as example on github. Had to clear the cache and then it just worked. Make sure you use the extension yaml and not yml.

Comment: @FrankB The issue was the "extends AbstractController", symfony recommended using abstract instead of regular controller. Malcolm showed how to do it while using abstractcontroller. Cache was being cleared, so it wasn't cache.

Comment: Glad to hear that your issue is solved. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to extend `Controller` instead of `AbstractController` class:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function myAction()
    {
        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
```

or better leave `AbstractController` and inject `knp_paginator` service into your action:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;

class MyController extends AbstractController
{

    public function myAction(PaginatorInterface $paginator)
    {
        $paginator->paginate()...
    }
```

Comment: Amazing, no idea how you even thought about AbstractController being the issue. Thank you so much. I'll attempt the edited version you just wrote out which allows me to still use AbstractController now. But, for what it's worth, changing AbstractController to controller worked.

Comment: Just tested with AbstractController method, works great too.

Comment: Hello sir, i am having a trouble to implement the pagination in my app(symfony 4).

Comment: @Darius How did you make it work with AbstractController ?

Comment: @mehmetsen80 see malcolm's answer, it shows you inject adding it into action variables. myAction(PaginatorInterface $paginator){ }

Comment: Note that Controller is [deprecated in Symfony 4.2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/a7e319d9e1316e2e18843f8ce15b67a8693e5bf9) and will be removed in Symfony 5, so you'd need to use the injection approach instead.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I use `AbstractController` and as `malcolm` says, it is beter to inject the service directrly in your action, even so, I call a method several times and I think that overwrite `getSubscribedServices` is clener for my porpuse.

```
public static function getSubscribedServices(): array
{
    $services = parent::getSubscribedServices();
    $services['fos_elastica.manager'] = RepositoryManagerInterface::class;
    $services['knp_paginator'] = PaginatorInterface::class;

    return $services;
}

private function listHandler(Search $search, Request $request, int $page): Response
{
    //...
    $repository = $this->container->get('fos_elastica.manager')->getRepository(Foo::class);
    //...

}
```

Comment: This seems to be right way. Works well for all kinds of services. The other solution did not work for `sonata.admin.pool` but this method worked.

Comment: This is the desired way in symfony 4.2

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the documentation. You must extend the base `Controller` class, or use dependency injection instead https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#service-parameters

Answer (score 0):

In my case i'm using symfony 4.3, I just injected the class to the methods as an argument and i'm done.

```
public function list(ProductManager $productManager)
{ 
   $products = $productManager->prepareProducts(); 
   return $products;
}
```