# Symfony 4 + Swift Mailer - error when sending email from 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

Symfony 4 app using Swift Mailer to send email.

I have written my controller logic and created a form, email all working on production server.

However in dev mode running from `php bin/console server:run` I get error:

```
Service "logger" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\PageController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "form.factory", "http_kernel", "parameter_bag", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "serializer", "session" and "twig" services.

Try using dependency injection instead.
```

I am just using the bundle as is. Why can I not send email from local dev environment?

Comment: So you're not using dependency injection? Why?

See this answer, it may be the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48740646/2661253

Answer (score -1):

You replaced somehow the Symfony's default container inside `App\Controller\PageController`. This message means bascically, that an object is not set up with its dependencies in the container. For details look here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html

Symfony uses the container pattern, which holds many objects inside a container that is accessable through the whole application.

Comment: The "somehow" is because they are using the now standard AbstractController.  This is basically a link only answer which really does not answer the question.  Might consider updating with an actual solution.

Comment: So I should extend Controller instead of AbstractControler in my controller class? Why doesn't Swift Mailer like AbstractController?