# Symfony 4 - Don't understand how to serialize entity with JMS Serializer

Tags: symfony, jms, circular-dependency, depth, serialization

I find myself stuck in my project Symfony 4.
In fact I have a User entity that implements **Serializable** and two `serialize` and `unserialize` (PHP) methods to serialize my entity.

Except that at one point I have a circular reference problem. I saw that I could correct this problem using the "depth option". And that **JMS Serializer** handled it easily.

So I installed the **JMS Serializer bundle**.

But after browsing several sites, several doc ', I do not understand how I have to modify my User entity to use the serialization of JMS instead of that of PHP, and use the depth.

```
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Adresse email de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email(message="Veuillez renseigner un email valide")
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * Rôles de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];


    /**
     * Ordres de mission de l'utilisateur
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdreMission", mappedBy="user")
     * @MaxDepth(2)
     */
    private $ordreMissions;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @MaxDepth(2)
     */
    private $entreprise;

/**
 * String representation of object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
 * @return string the string representation of the object or null
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Constructs the object
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
 * @param string $serialized <p>
 * The string representation of the object.
 * </p>
 * @return void
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list (
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
        $this->password,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
```

I added **@MaxDepth(2)** on my "**ordreMission**" and "**entreprises**" attributes and I would like to use JMS Serializer to serialise my entity, and **use the depth option**.

But I don't understand how do it

Answer (score 1):

You have few methods to use the **JMSSerializerBundle** :

1. Directly from your Entity, using `@Annotations` ans `@MaxDepth` like this :

   ```
   namespace YourNamespace\Entity;
   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
   use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;
   use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\MaxDepth as MaxDepth;

   /**
    * User
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="user")
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="YourBundle\Repository\ProgrammerRepository")
    * @Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")
    */ 
   class User implements UserInterface
   {
     /**
      * @var integer
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      * @Serializer\Expose
      */
     private $id;

     /*[...]*/

     /**
      * Ordres de mission de l'utilisateur
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrdreMission", mappedBy="user")
      * @MaxDepth(2)
      */
     private $ordreMissions;


     /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Entreprise", inversedBy="users")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
      * @MaxDepth(2)
      */
     private $entreprise;
   }
   ```
2. From the controller code, on an action :

```
    $serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');
    $serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
    $data = $serializer->deserialize($jsonData, 'YourNamespace\User', 'json');
```

3. With config file : See [Configuration reference](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time! So in my case I must use the first solution, it is the most suitable for me. However, as I understand it, I no longer implement ```Serializable``` and therefore I do not have my old methods anymore, and everything goes through ```JMS Serializer``` ? Knowing that before, I had my attributes ```($ id, $ email, $ password)``` that were part of the list for the serialization, it means that if I want to "reproduce" with JMS, I have to use the annotation ```@Serializer\Expose``` on these 3 fields?

Comment: And other question, if I use the ```@Serializer\ExclusionPolicy("all")``` annotation, my $ordreMission and $entreprise won't be serialized if I don't write the ```@Serializer\Expose```, no ?

Comment: That exactly that !

Comment: Okay, the problem is that I do not get the same thing with JMS. Basically, if I implemented Serializable, it's because I had an error on some pages because of User entity : ```Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 7899 of 17631 bytes```. Having implemented Serializable and having put the id, the email and the password in the list, it solved this old problem. But here, using JMS, if I try to reproduce this schema by including id, email, and password, I fall back on my old departure error before the current problem

Comment: Suggest to start with a simple entity and try to get JMSSerializer working and understanding. Then move to more difficult like your User and trying any association type individually. If you don't have understanding of Serialisation, JMSSerializer and so on it's hard to achieve all at once, especially here. No offense though!

Comment: I wonder if I have to do some configuration to say that serialization is done thanks) JMS? Because by putting the implementation of Serializable and my old methods, and adding over the JMS annotation of the beginning to exclude everything, I no longer have my error on offset, as if JMS was ignored

Comment: Have a look to https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles.html to have a proper configuration of 3rd party bundles.

Comment: But with Symfony Flex, it's automatic no ?

Comment: Yes, but could you have a look to this file, to ensure JmsSerializerBundle is enabled ? You can also testing that it be properly installed , calling $serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer'); from a controller...

Comment: Hmm, in my bundles.php, I've ```JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],```. But from a controller, with : ```$serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');```, I've ```Service "jms_serializer" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "App\Controller\Admin\AdminValidateurController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about....```

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/713

Comment: I think I understand what was wrong. I used ```composer require jms/serializer-bundle``` from a website. But at this moment, I just found the "official" website, with other "composer require" : ```composer require jms/serializer```. I think this is the good bundle

Comment: I don't undertsand ... I have to use https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer or http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle ?

Comment: You have already installed the correct bundle, when running : `composer require jms/serializer-bundle`, verify on your config.yml file that autowiring is enabled

Comment: Have a look to that : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740064/symfony-4-knppaginator-bundle-service-not-found-even-though-it-exists-in-app

Comment: Yes autowiring is enabled. But I have a question. Me at no time in my controllers I do not call serialization functions, do we agree? I manage everything from my entity thanks to the annotations. Only in my User class did I intervene. Except that in my application, it is possible that at a certain moment, my token is deserialized automatically to make verifications (I imagine), from AbstractToken.php (function unserialize ()). Will symfony automatically understand that I'm using JMS Serializer?

Comment: And in my controller, to make a test, I declared ```private $serializer```. And in my constructor I declared : ```SerializerInterface $serializer```, and now In my controller, I can access to the $serializer. But the problem is the same, I think my token is badly deserialized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204063/discussion-between-weenesta-mathieu-dormeval-and-eronn).